# What is difference between Map.fetch(key, value) and Map.fetch!(key, value)

Tags: elixir

https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html#fetch/2 and https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html#fetch!/2 are slightly different but there is no discussion as to what is different.

The document does mention the first is "inlined by the compiler" and the later is exception raised.

Is there a rule of thumb I should have on when to use one and not the other, vice versa?

regards

Comment: In general the bang version (!) of any function means that it may raise an exception.  Hence `File.open`--no potential exception.  `File.open!`--potential exception.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is the return value:

```
iex(1)> map = %{foo: 42}
%{foo: 42}
iex(2)> Map.fetch(map, :foo)
{:ok, 42}
iex(3)> Map.fetch(map, :bar)
:error
iex(4)> Map.fetch!(map, :foo)
42
iex(5)> Map.fetch!(map, :bar)
** (KeyError) key :bar not found in: %{foo: 42}
    (stdlib) :maps.get(:bar, %{foo: 42})
```

`fetch` returns `{:ok, value}` if the key exists and `:error` otherwise. `fetch!` returns just the value and if it's not present it raises an error.

`fetch` makes it easy to handle the case where the key doesn't exist with pattern matching while you'll usually want to use `fetch!` when you expect the key to exist in the map and a lack of it existing is likely a bug in your code.

Comment: Thank you Dogbert - much appreciated.